# Testing Promise.all

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an async function that looks something like this:

```
const myMethod = async () => {
  await Promise.all(
    someIds.map((id) => {
      someMethodThatReturnsPromise(id);
    }); 
  );
  doSomethingElseAfterPromisesResolve();
};
```

This function contains a bug because it uses curly braces in its map function but doesn't return each promise. The Promise.all consumes the undefined return value and silently proceeds to the next statement, without waiting. The problem can be corrected by using parentheses instead of braces, or by including an explicit return statement.

My question is, how can I test this? I know I can use Promise.resolve() or Promise.reject() to simulate different states of the promise, and mock the return values of the inner method, but that doesn't really cover the problem. Outside a full blown integration test, how can I prevent the above error with a test?

Comment: Do you mean test it in your application, or in unit testing?

Comment: why not having a style checker that tells you not to forget your `return`s?  sounds like a better prevention mechanism...

Comment: Barmar - I was looking for a unit test to cover the problem. It's our teams practice to write tests covering any bugs we fix.

Comment: @JSelser To provide dummy `return` statement at the end of each function? That's the most disgusting thing about Coffee. Fortunately, that's JS, not Coffee.

Comment: JSelser - I found this - looks like it might do the trick:  https://eslint.org/docs/rules/array-callback-return

Comment: I would recommend not to ignore the result of `Promise.all`. If you fulfill your promises with some meaningful value, and then use those result values in `doSomethingElseAfterPromisesResolve`, bugs like the one you describe will quickly surface.

Comment: @estus seems you can have ESLint complain when using callbacks in promises, so you dont need to have dummy `return`s. Id say a test for this is weird, having a linter sounds better to me

Comment: @JSelser Yes, array-callback-return looks like a good rule because the lack of return in these methods always indicates a mistake or misused method. Still, as any other code, this one needs to be tested. That it wasn't possible to detect the mistake suggests that unit tests don't provide enough coverage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the issue is not that `Promise.all()` accepts null, it doesnt. What it accepts is arrays of the kind of `[null]` or `[undefined]` (which are 2 different things, actually)

As I mentioned in my comments, testing `Promise.all()` is not something I would do, it's third party code, you should be testing your own, so I think having a linter check for such bugs is a far superior solution

That being said, you are entitled to your opinions, I'll merely point out a possibility for achieving what you want. That is: **monkey patching**

You could overwrite the `Promise.all()` like so:

```
let originalAll = Promise.all;

Promise.all = (promises) => {
  // you could check several other things
  // but this covers what you wanted, right?
  let isArrayWithBlanks = promises.includes(null) || promises.includes(undefined);

  return isArrayWithBlanks
    ? Promise.reject("NO!")
    : originalAll(promises);
};
```

Now you can easily write a test given you use this monkey patched `Promise.all` throughout your project. You decide where to place that code

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I would stub both the `someMethodThatReturnsPromise` and `doSomethingElseAfterPromisesResolve` functions, returning any value from both.

Then ensure that `someIds` has multiple values.

Your assertions could then be:

1. someMethodThatReturnsPromise is called once for each item in the `someIds` array
2. doSomethingElseAfterPromisesResolve is called

Comment: Steve, that's what I had originally, and the test passed. Even though I was failing to return the values to the map, Promise.all was accepting the undefined return value and moving on.

Comment: Ah yes I see what you mean. I&#39;m not sure you could catch that in tests alone in this instance. You don&#39;t really have much to check during a test to assert that undefined has been returned from the promises. You would need additional application code such as a return to be able to at what you need